# real-time counter with format dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm

Tags: netlogo

How can I create a real-time counter with format dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm in Netlogo and stretching from   1st August 00:00 to 15 October 00:00 ? I will need to use hours and minutes of the counter in numerical format to integrate this information in statistical model.

This is my beginning of code to create a counter and to use hours and minutes of the counter in a statistical model (for example, `y = beta0 + beta1 * hourMinute`).

```
extensions [time] 

globals[dateStart dateEnd]

patches-own[y]

to setup
let beta0 0.6
let beta1 0.1
set dateStart time:create "2013/08/01 00:00"
set dateEnd time:create "2013/10/31 00:00"

ask patches [ 
if not time:is-equal (dateStart) (dateEnd) [
let hour time:show dateStart "HH"
let minute time:show dateStart "mm"
let hourMinute read-from-string hour + ( (read-from-string minute) / 60 )
set y beta0 + beta1 * hourMinute
set dateStart time:plus dateStart 1.0 "minutes" ] ]
end
```

The problem is that I don't know to increase by an increment of 1 minute the variable `dateStart` until the variable `dateEnd`. With my code, `dateStart` is always equal to `2013-08-01 00:01`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't completely clear to me, but I think this is probably relevant:

The time extension by Colin Sheppard and Steve Railsback has functionality for manipulating dates and times; see https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/ for details.

Comment: Thank you very much Seth for time extension. It's exactly what I needed.